# java fixed textpane area get scrollbar if necessary

Tags: java, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jtextpane, area

I'm trying to make a GUI in java, and I want to make an interface where I have multiple textpanes with a fixed area, and, as such, depending on the width of the window, I may get a scrollbar if necessary

like this

[image]

what is the best way to achieve something like this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) can be used in such a case. Here's the official tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html